# Writing HTML in PHP file

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and so I wonder what is better: to write html code in php echoing or printing it or close the PHP tags and write html "pure html"?
Is there are differences or it is just a matter of taste?

For example
1:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php 
       (php code goes here)
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

2:

```
<?php 
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
   (php logic goes here)
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Googling didn't give me an exact answer, so I'm sorry if there are topics like this.

Comment: Better is to do like in example one! :)

Comment: php code in html is clearer for me, example 2 won't even work.

Comment: i agree with the above people, first example is far clearer

Comment: It is a matter of readability, example 1 is just more readable and you can easily edit the form this way as most ide's will finish off your tags for you but not when using echo.

Comment: I've always done it like example one. I've seen a few cases with example 2, but they're usually pretty messy.

Comment: example 2 is wrong ( I updated it to be correct). You need the php tags at the beginning and end (optional) of the file. Having them in the content while using php outside will break. Example 1 is the proper way to do it. Example 2, is bad practice and causes more overhead than necessary

Comment: While it could be considered a question prone to opiniated answers, I think all opinions will be the same in that case and point to example 1 for readibility. There are cases though where you might want to build a string variable then echo the whole string to avoid entering and exiting PHP code too many times.

Comment: Why would you echo HTML if you can just write HTML. The code will load up faster since PHP needs less time to parse.

Comment: Define "better". Are you concerned with performance, other developers, or best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Manual says

`For outputting large blocks of text, dropping out of PHP parsing mode is generally more efficient than sending all of the text through echo() or print().`

In simple words

If you have a large amount of html do not use `echo` to print it.
Because all those html will pass through PHP interpreter, and will take some time (maybe negligible) to parse.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 2):

Best of all, of course, separate logic and presentation, but if you want to embed the php code in the page, you should use the first option, so usually write templates. And here's the second option is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a reason to be using php in such situation. Stick to HTML, CSS and Javascript for things that don't really need php.

Example 1 seems cleaner and simpler.

But in the other side, if you're trying to learn php it would be good practice to use it for everything, immerse yourself in that language I guess!

Answer (score 1):

It's a personal choice.

Personally; I look at the amount of HTML. Is there more HTML then PHP? I use example 1. But if there's a lot of PHP and I need to create (for example) a `select`, I use example 2.

Either way, it is best to keep HTML and PHP as seperated as possible, so probably you will use example 1 the most.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is fine.

but its depend on what exactly you are developing if you are developing frontend UI then example 1 is fine.

In case of backend or more dynamic functions or in simple word more php code then Example 2 work.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE is teaching you to not echo it.

Most IDEs wouldn't help you with markup if you echo your HTML code because they think it's a normal string.

Also it's desirable to seperate logic and presentation.

I prefer the first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html> 
 <title>HTML with PHP</title>
 <body>
 <h1>My Example</h1>

 <?php
 //your php code here
 ?>

 <b>Here is some more HTML</b>

 <?php
 //more php code
 ?>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD NOT use inline PHP in HTML code because:

1. Any type of content sent before php has a chance to change headers (example of this is redirecting to a different page) can no longer be done. Once headers are sent thats it.
2. By putting HTML all in a variable or echo call to display all at once is a great way to keep code readability and only need one php tag.
3. If you use inline PHP with complex code, you can easily lose where your loops, conditionals, and/or functions begin/end.

My opinion is if you want to use html code in PHP without having to quote it all, use [HEREDOC format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

UPDATE:

After doing some research, I found out that echoing static HTML is not good on performance. Look at [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180504/126437) on the topic. In short it explains that you should use templates to display static HTML which I can agree with. However, If you are using data from a database consistently and the data is dynamic you should use pure PHP.

Also, if you have conditional statements with echos inside, PHP will need to do the logic for the output anyway so echoing parts of a page inside a conditional (in my opinion) is better then closing php mid-conditional.

As always this topic is pretty opinion based and performance-wise inline PHP is better. If you are going for manageability and readability than pure PHP is the way to go. (imagine 1000+ lines of inline PHP and tell me that its easier to read then pure PHP)

See [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it) and **ALL** its answers before making up your mind.

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234698/126437) is another good post by a high rep contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you would want to use [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) for the view (displaying HTML content) using PHP.

Twig known to be faster than tradional PHP views. Maybe a little of research on this helps.